# Solidity mapping struct and search question, how to search by name?

Tags: solidity, struct

In this example, how would I write a function for

> getPersonByName(string _name) returns (_address) {}

```
// Code Example
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

contract Project
{
    struct Person {
        string name;
        uint funds;
    }

    // this is the mapping for which we want the
    // compiler to automatically generate a getter.
    mapping(address => Person) public people;

    // this is what the automatically generated getter
    // looks like (we don't need to implement this ourselves).
    function getPerson(address id)
        public
        returns (string name, uint funds)
    {
        // copy the data into memory
        Person memory p = people[id];

        // break the struct's members out into a tuple
        // in the same order that they appear in the struct
        return (p.name, p.funds);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not possible to implement in your current contract. But if you need this,  you have to tweak your smart contract.

When you declare a mapping, it's a key-value pair but you can not get key from value. Ideally what you want is getting key from value and value from key. This is what we call bidirectional map. Even conventional programming languages like Java does not support [bidirectional-map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783020/bidirectional-map).

Now coming to  solution part, you may declare another mapping with

```
mapping(string=> address) getAddressFromName;
```

This is the best I could think of as of now. Even if you were able to loop through mapping (which is not the case), I would have recommended this solution as lopping may create issues when data in mapping increases.

**Edit:**

When you add a user, you push the name and address of the sender to `getAddressFromName` mapping. For eg,

```
function addPerson (string _name, uint _funds) public {
   Person memory newPerson = Person(_name, _funds);
   people[msg.sender] = newPerson;
   getAddressFromName[_name] = msg.sender;
}

function getPersonByName(string _name) public view returns(address){
    return getAddressFromName[_name];
}
```

Also, note that key to mapping is unique, so when you try to add a new value with the same key, it doesn't  add a new key it replaces the previous value corresponding to that key.

Comment: Okay, maybe its just cuz Im a complete newb in this space...

if I had:

struct Person {
        string name;
        string gender;
        uint funds;
    }

and I use: 

mapping(string=> address)  getAddressFromName;

what string is going to be used for the key?

I think I am really missing the concept of how mapping defines the relationship...

Comment: I think the logic for that answer will work, quick question: I had trouble using remix and using the declaration string. Would it be more usable to have the bytes32 declaration instead?

Comment: You will have issues if you try to declare the mapping public. Since a string is bytes array and when you declare a public mapping, the automatic getters are generated. Now since solidity doesn't support dynamic arrays. You can not declare a public mapping having a string. So you can either use bytes32 instead of string or just do not declare mapping public.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a simple solution, for a similar situation I had a mapping  of persons

```
struct Person{
    uint id;
    string fName;
    string lName;
}

mapping (address => Person) Persons;
```

and I was trying to make a filter to restrict the access to some functions so I had to test if the sender exist on the mapping or not. So I had the idea of adding a property of type address to the struct so that I can test on the key

Final version:

```
modifier only {
    require(Persons[msg.sender].Myaddress == "some address");
    _;
}

struct Person {
    uint id;
    string fName;
    string lName;
    address Myaddress;
}

mapping (address => Person) Persons;
```

and it's working well, so what do you think about this solution is't good?